# OpenGL+GLFW glGenVertexArrays returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c, macos, opengl, glfw

In trying to move into using "modern" OpenGL (basically 3.2+), I've run into some troubles running basic code (derived from both [here](https://open.gl/content/code/c2_triangle.txt) and [here](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html)) using GLFW, GLEW, and OpenGL.

My first problem is that with the below code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

void checkErr(const char* msg) {
    GLenum err = glGetError();

    if (err != 0) {
        printf("@ \"%s\": %d\n", msg, err);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        printf("@ \"%s\": successful\n", msg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    const GLubyte* glslVersion = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
    printf ("Renderer:       %s\n", renderer);
    printf ("OpenGL version: %s\n", version);
    printf ("GLSL version:   %s\n", glslVersion);

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    checkErr("Gen VAO");
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    checkErr("Bind VAO");

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    checkErr("Gen VBO");

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    checkErr("Bind VBO");
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    checkErr("VBO data");

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    checkErr("Compile vert shader");

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    checkErr("Compile frag shader");

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    checkErr("Link program");
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    checkErr("Use program");

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    checkErr("Enable vertex attrib");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    checkErr("Describe vert data");

    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm immediately running into `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors on the very first step of setting up the vertex array object.

I've done a fair bit of research regarding OS X's flimsy OpenGL support, but so far most of the things I've modified in this code has done nothing more but produce a completely black screen (that is, when I removed the crashing behavior of the `checkError` helper function).

For reference, I'm running on an early 2015 MacBook Pro w/Retina, OS X v10.11.3, and the output of the version info from my above program lists as follows:

```
Renderer:       Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100
OpenGL version: 4.1 INTEL-10.12.13
GLSL version:   4.10
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just *assumed* that your error was generated by `glGenVertexArrays`. But that is not the case. It is generated by `glewInit`. And this is because GLEW is just broken on core profile opengl: it uses `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` to query the extension string, which is not available in core prodiles and generates a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error (1280).

Normally, `glewInit` will then abort with return code `GL_FALSE`. However, the "workaround" of setting `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE` will make it going on, ignoring the error, and querying all the extension pointers anyway. This is now broken in at least 3 different regards:

1. All the GLEW variables for querying the avialibility of specific extensions return false even when the extension is available.
2. It will retrieve function pointers for extension functions whose availibility hasn't been advertised by the implementation. It is not guaranteed that those pointers will be `NULL`, but calling these would be undefined behavior. Together with 1, this means you have no way of checking the availibility of any extension, except by manually doing the stuff glew is actually there for to do for you.
3. It will leave the GL context in an error state.

As a quick & dirty hack, you can just add a `glGetError()` right after `glewInit`, to read the error away. After I did that, your code produced the expected white triangle on my implementation (NVIDIA/Linux).

A better fix is probably to switch over to another GL loader which does properly work with core profiles, for example [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad). Switching over will not be really hard, as only that init function has to be replaced. Note that glad is not a loader library, but a python script which generates a loader *source* file for your needs, so you don't need to link another library, but just have to add another source file to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help @derhass, I'm actually not using GLEW anywhere else, so simply just removing GLEW entirely worked to produce the triangle! I've definitely run into glad before, but couldn't understand precisely what extra value it added in comparison to GLFW, GLEW, etc. But I'll for sure take a look now.

Comment: Since you are on OSX, a gl loader is not strictly required for accessing the core functionality of OpenGL. However, if you intent to write protable code, you can't do it that way. Have a look at [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) and [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) OpenGL wiki article to learn what GL loaders are about.